# Amelia imputations in R to exclude participants who did not receive the items

Tags: r, imputation

I am trying to use amelia to impute my data using a single expectation-maximisation imputation. However, I have two groups within my sample, some of which did not receive all of the survey items. Therefore, I do not want to impute responses for these participants. If participants answered `'yes'` to the `'Seen.Psychologist'` item they were presented with all of the items if they answered `'no'` 16 of the items were not presented to them as they were irrelevant. The following variables were not received by those participants: `CulturalSafety_var`, `"Practical"`, `"Referral"`, and `"Wait.time"`.

My current imputation is as follows.

```
am_imp <- amelia(x = data[, c(SafetyBehaviour_var, CulturalSafety_var, 
                              Anxiety_var, SelfStigma_var, Disclosure_var, 
                              PublicStigma_var, Motivation_var, 
                              NonAttendance_var, "Employment", "Education",
                              "Referral", "Ethnicity", "Wait.time", "Practical")], 
                 noms = c("Practical"), 
                 m = 1, 
                 boot.type = "none")
```

One option would be to not include those items in the imputation but then it would run into other issues with the rest of the script. For example when I combine the imputed data with the original data set.

Another way around it (as suggested by my supervisor) is as follows:

1. Do a first round of imputation using only the variables that everyone should have seen, with the whole sample.
2. Do a second round of imputations with only the variables that were presented if participants had said yes to seeing the psychologist and using only the those participants.
3. Combine (rbind) the imputed data from #2 with the rows on those variables for the participants who hadn't seen a psychologist ( a whole bunch of completely missing data)
4. Combine (cbind) the imputed datasets from #1 and #3 and any other remaining variables you didn't apply imputation to, being careful about the ordering of participants in the datasets.

However this would mean the imputations wouldn't be as accurate given they are based on only a subset of variables.

I am hoping there is a wonderful amelia guru who might have a suggestion I could try....

Answer (score 0):

Your supervisor's suggestions makes sense to me. Consider following table:

```
seen psych.  Imp. 1 (restr.)  Imp. 2 (ext.)    used
      FALSE             TRUE          FALSE  Imp. 1
       TRUE             TRUE           TRUE  Imp. 2
```

The first column divides your sample in two sub-samples, seen psychologist or not. The `Imp*` columns indicate if included in imputation or not. Column `used` shows what will be used to `rbind` the final data set.

Imputation *1* is applied on the restricted variable set, i.e. information that's jointly available for the whole sample.

Imputation *2* is applied on the extended variable set which is only available for the `seen psych. == TRUE`. It considers the extended variables `CulturalSafety_var, Practical, ...` to be imputed (and also uses other variables for prediction!). Here you may use `Imp. 1` (subsetted for `seen psych. == TRUE`) as the base which should already be complete.

As shown in `used` column, for the `seen psych. == FALSE` only `Imp. 1` is used. For the `seen psych. == TRUE` we use `Imp. 2` which includes `Imp. 1` and the newly imputed extended variables. The `Imp. 1` variables shouldn't have changed anymore in `Imp. 2`. The extended variables are imputed with maximum information; you may not use the `seen psych. == FALSE` to predict the extended variables, because there isn't any information.

Hence, in the final `rbind`ed data set, all the restricted variables should be complete, and the extended variables should have missings for the `seen psych. == FALSE`.

(What you could consider is to weigh up the tradeoff between imputing the *restricted* variables of the `seen psych. == TRUE` as described above, or include the extended variables for their prediction. However, in the latter case you may only use the `seen psych. == TRUE` subset for imputation and you will lose all the information of the `seen psych. == FALSE`, and the imputation result would be worse.)